# How to remove a char in string using vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

```
string Example 1 : abc / 
string Example 2 : abc / cdf / / 
string Example 3 : abc / / / /
string Example 4 : / / / / / 
string Example 5 : abc / / xyz / / /
```

I need to remove the slashes in string with many scenarios. I guess the scenarios is self explanatory in the expected result below.

Result:

```
    string Example 1 : abc 
    string Example 2 : abc / cdf 
    string Example 3 : abc  
    string Example 4 :  
    string Example 5 : abc / xyz
```

How do I do this usng vb.net?

Comment: what about the white space?

Comment: Guessing that you want to remove slashes except when they separate other characters. If the solidus is a separator then leave only one, i.e. "a / b / / c" -> "a / b / c". Did you write any code yet?

Comment: @HABO You are correct. I missed that out. Updated the Question.

Comment: Yes, if you have this string: `abc / / cdf / / `, what should it yeild? I'm guessing `abc / cdf`, is that correct?

Comment: Regex. Remove any leading slashes ignoring whitespace, remove any trailing slashes ignoring whitespace, collapse any other occurrences (ignoring whitespace) to a single slash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim s As String '= ...
Dim aux() As String

aux = s.Split(New Char() {"/"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
s = String.Join("/", aux)
```

You may want to handle the white spaces:

```
aux = s.Split("/ ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
s = String.Join(" / ", aux)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this result in a string with extra white space in it? Might need to `.Trim()` the strings in the array before you can join them.

Answer (score 2):

```
Function RemoveTrailingSlash(ByVal s as String) As String
    'Note that space is included in this array
    Dim slash() As Char = "/ ".ToCharArray()
    s = s.TrimEnd()
    While s.EndsWith("/")
        s = s.TrimEnd(slash)
    End While
    Return s
End Function
```

Typed directly into the reply window (not tested!), but I think it will work.

Comment: This functioned for the original examples 1 - 4, but not for the newly added example 5.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Rexexp expression. Bellow should work:

```
 "(/\s+)+$"
```

it search for:

1. '/'
2. followed by one or more white-chars: \s+
3. multiple times - expression: (/\s+)+
4. in the end of string ($)